# Assign a jquery value to text inside the same PHP passage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

This presently resides inside some PHP in the web page source:

```
echo("<span class=\"somevalue\"></span>");
```

It works, the value is expressed on the page where the PHP instruction is invoked.  But now--instead of an echo() announcement--how can the value instead be assigned to a text variable I can use elsewhere in the PHP?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does this question have to do with JavaScript and jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the string to a variable

```
$mySpan = "<span class=\"somevalue\"></span>";
```

And then echo the variable anywhere later in the code.  You can define $mySpan at the top of the script or define it in a separate file and include that file in any other file you will need the variable.

Answer (score 0):

i think its work

```
echo '<span class=\"'.$somevalue.'"\></span>';
```